# It's about Linux soft links with one source and several destinations :)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Let's assume that we've several non-identical versions of the same folder in different locations as follows:

- `/in/some/location/version1`
- `/different/path/version2`
- `/third/place/version3`

Each version of them contains `callerFile`, which is a pre-compiled executable that we can't control its working functionality. this `callerFile` will create and edit a folder called `cache`

- `/some/fourth/destination/cache`

So we've contradiction between the setting of every version so what I want to do is converting the `/some/fourth/destination/cache` to a link with 3 different destinations

- `/some/fourth/destination/cache` --> `/in/some/location/version1/cache`
- `/some/fourth/destination/cache` --> `/different/path/version2/cache`
- `/some/fourth/destination/cache` --> `/third/place/version3/cache`

so for example:

- if `/in/some/location/version1/callerFile` calls `/some/fourth/destination/cache` it should redirected to `/in/some/location/version1/cache`
- and if `/different/path/version2/callerFile` calls `/some/fourth/destination/cache` it should redirected to `/different/path/version2/cache`
- and if `/third/place/version3/callerFile` calls `/some/fourth/destination/cache` it should redirected to `/third/place/version3/cache`

So, How can I do so on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit Operating System?

Comment: I think you'll find this is what application config was invented for... Having symlinks pointing to different folders based on the caller at OS level is not a good approach. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to test the availability of the multi-destination from one source link as a Linux challenges in learning process for a beginner :) or I'll be screwed :( so I need some experts ideas about this thing

Comment: new user tip: you can upvote/accept some answer if you find it helpful ;-)

Comment: It's generally helpful :) but I've not enough reputation yet as it requires 15 reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have no control over what callerFile actually does, I mean it does what it wants and always the same, so the conclusion is you need to modify it's environment. This will be quite advanced trick, requiring deep experience of Linux kernel and Unix programming in general, and you should think over if it's worth. It will also require root priviledges on the machine where your callerFile binary exists.

Solution I'd propose would be creating an executable ( or some script calling one of exec()  family function ), which will prepare special environment ( or make sure it's ready to use ), based on "mount -o bind" or unshare() system call.

Like said, playing with so called "execution context", is quite advanced trick. Theoretically you could also try some autofs-like solution, however you'll probably end up with the same, and bindmount/unshare will be probably more effective than some FS-detection daemon. I wouldn't recommend diving into FUSE, for the same reason. And playing with some over-complicated game with symlinks is probably not the way too.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/unshare.txt

Note: whatever "callerFile" binary does, I'm pretty sure it won't check its own filename, which makes possible replacing it with something else in-between, which will do exec() on "callerFileRenamed".

As I understand it, basically what you want is to get different result with the same activity, distinguished by some condition external to activity itself, like, for example, returning different list for "ls" in same directory,  based upon e.g. UID of user who issued "ls" command, without modifying some ./ls program binary.

Comment: Can I understand that the link with one source and several destinations is NOT valid concept at all? Or it's some valid in Linux but it'll NOT solve the proposed situation?

Comment: Yep. Links, actually, works some different way than you understand. You can have as many sinks in the building as you want, however it still doesn't make river to flow backwards, as water is supposed to flow from up to bottom anyway.. Theoretically maybe Neverland-born experimental systems like Plan9 support such vague concept of links, but they probably support Captain Hook with eight hands too, if you know what I mean :)

Comment: hahahaha =))) thank you very much for your great help, quick response and wise directions :)